# How do I increase the font size of the message list in Geary?

Tags: theme, geary

I just installed Geary and it doesn't seem possible to change the font size of the message list and the text on my laptop screen is too small.

Is there a way to modify this without affecting the rest of Gnome?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

From Preferences, I enabled the use single key email shortcuts, and then zoom in with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>. This solved the issue.

Comment: The "Ctrl +" keyboard shortcut only seems to affect the text of the email pain on the right, not the *list* of emails. I also want to increase the size of the text of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Geary uses the Gnome desktop font size for its email list font. To change this, use the Gnome Tweak app to set the "Interface Text." Note that this will affect your entire system, not just the Geary email list font.